# Counting nodes in an XML document within Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently migrated to Chrome from Firefox (bye bye Firebug, sniff) and one of the only tools I cannot yet replicate is the "XML Developer Toolbar" - specifically within that extension I used the *Node counting functionality* which is invaluable when writing XML export scripts.

Can anyone please recommend a Chrome based alternative?

Cut me some slack here please. I posted this on superUser where it was (inexplicably imho) put on hold.

I think other coders out there have the same requirement, and that they might have the solution. Fingers crossed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess you'll have to write your own extension.

Comment: ha, yes maybe :( I just hoped someone had a trick, if not an extension

Comment: Well, you can make a *bookmarklet* (example: [ActiveTable](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/07/16/activetable-bookmarklet/)) with  `javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName('*').length)` to show the number of elements on click. Or an advanced one that injects a dynamic tooltip/toolbar.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's genius! I've done it and it works PERFECTLY. It's much better than before because it's ONLY the functionality that I need and it's one click instead of having to specify the node! You simply make a whole html "page" and in the body add: `<a href="javascript: (function () {alert(document.getElementsByTagName('name_of_node').length); }());">Count XML nodes on a page: put me in your favorites</a>` so please post that as an answer and I will accept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@wOxxOm declined to post this as an answer, so on his behalf, and tweaked slightly by me, this works perfectly as browser bookmarklet:

```
<a href="javascript: (function () {alert(document.getElementsByTagName('name_of_node').length)‌​; }());">Count XML nodes on a page: put me in your favorites</a>
```